Azure pipelines Docker@2 containerRegistry
In azure pipelines, I have a variable that's declared as follows
variables:
  - name: acr_svc_conn

In my pipeline, I set this value as shown
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=acr_svc_conn;]$ACR"

When I try to use this in my Docker@2 task as shown
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: '$(acr_svc_conn)'
    command: 'login'
  displayName: Login to ACR

I get this error
##[error]Docker registry service connection not specified.
##[error]Unhandled: Docker registry service connection not specified.

Any thoughts? I've tried combinations of ${{ variable.acr_svc_conn }} and variables['acr_svc_conn'] and nothing has worked. Of course, when I hardcode the connection name it works, but I'd like to see if it can be done dynamically.

I tried removing that semicolon ; as suggested, and also added an echo step. Re-ran the pipeline, and I can see the variable is populated, but the Docker@2 task does not seem to recognize or accept a variable, it seems.

The error message seems to be the same, but that's not what I'm encountering. I know my pipeline runs, when I hardcode the service connection name in the containerRegistry part of the Docker@2` task, but I can't use a variable

I tried with single and double quotes and without quotes, but the same issue persists, unfortunately

Service connections are protected resources, i.e. only specific users and pipelines within the project can access them. This means their values must be known at compile time, so that the service connections can be authorized (or not) before a specific pipeline runs.
Having said that, you won't be able to change the value of a variable used as a service connection after the pipeline starts like this:
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=acr_svc_conn;]$ACR"

And the error you're getting makes sense if variable acr_svc_conn is empty by default:
##[error]Docker registry service connection not specified.
##[error]Unhandled: Docker registry service connection not specified.

Workaround
Specify all the possible values for the service connections in variables and/or variable templates and then use template expressions to get/set the right variables or template.
Example:
parameters:
  - name: azureRegion
    displayName: 'Azure Region'
    type: string
    default: eastus
    values:
      - eastus
      - westeurope

variables:
  - template: /pipelines/variables/${{ parameters.azureRegion }}-variables.yaml

steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: '${{ variables.acr_svc_conn }}'
      command: 'login'
    displayName: Login to ACR

  # other tasks here

/pipelines/variables/eastus-variables.yaml
# East US specific variables

variables:
  - name: acr_svc_conn
    value: my-eastus-container-registry
  
  # other variables

/pipelines/variables/westeurope-variables.yaml
# West-Europe specific variables

variables:
  - name: acr_svc_conn
    value: my-westeurope-container-registry
  
  # other variables


Thanks! I took a similar approach as you have suggested. Glad that you explained why this is happening and it helps a lot!
